# Is there a neat way to serialize a Perl hash into an HTML querystring

Tags: html, perl, serialization

I have a perl script using CGI.

The browser calls it with some parameters.

I want to take those parameters, modify some of them and then send back a redirect with a new querystring representing the modified parameters.

I know that I could do this, like this:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new()
my %vars = $cgi->Vars
$vars{'modify_me'} .=' more stuff';

my $serialized = join '&', map {$_.'='.$cgi->escapeHTML($vars{$_})} keys %vars;
```

However, this just feels like it might be missing something. In addition, it doesn't do anything to handle multivalued parameters. Who knows what else it fails to do.

So, is there a module out there that just deals with this problem? I'm not interested in reinventing a wheel that a more talented wright wrought. Right?

Comment: Oh yeah... if there's just a better way to achieve this end, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [URI module](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) is your friend. It has a `query_form` method that takes a hash, hashref or arrayref of parameters and generates a query string from it.

It will URL Encode your data for you (and note that you do want it URL Encoded and *not* HTML Encoded).

So you might have something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use URI;

my $q = CGI->new;

my @data = map {
        my $name = $_;
        my @values = $q->param($name);
        my $value;
        if (scalar @values == 1) {
            ($value) = @values;
        } else {
            $value = \@values;
        }

        if ($name eq "foo") {
            $value = "replaced";
        }
        ($name, $value);
    } $q->param;

my $uri = URI->new('http://example.com/myAlternative.cgi');
$uri->query_form(\@data);

print $q->redirect(
    -uri=> $uri,
    -status => 301
     );
```

Comment: This is wrong. query_form converts spaces into '+' (plusses) which is invalid for URLs. They should be %20. 
Input: $uri->query_form( [ 'foo bar' => 1 ] );
Output: http://example.com/myAlternative.cgi?foo+bar=1

Comment: @AndyRay — `+` is not invalid for a URL. That's why when you submit a regular HTML form, any spaces you type are converted to `+` characters.

Comment: I understand, but it's invalid for a space. A space is %20. URL encoding a space to a + changes the data in the URL, so you can't use it to properly encode any url with spaces

Comment: @AndyRay — `%20` is the standard way to encode spaces in URLs, `+` was used in an older version of the URI spec but is still valid. The isn't defined as a space in the URI spec but it is in the HTML spec and the CGI spec (and other server side URL parsers follow the CGI spec since to do otherwise would stop HTML forms from working).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Data::URIEncode](http://search.cpan.org/~rhandom/Data-URIEncode-0.11/lib/Data/URIEncode.pm) or [URI::QueryParam](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.59/URI/QueryParam.pm)?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, there's a way to achieve my specific need using just the `CGI` module. However, the other answers cover a wider need, to serialize an arbitrary hash.

If you want to modify incoming parameters and then create a link to the same script with modified parameters you can do this:

```
my $params = $cgi->Vars;

$ Modify the values in hash that $params references

my $new_url = $cgi->self_url(); # URL with modified parameters
```